# How to Increase allocated memory for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have made an app but eventually it has become much larger. So while building it I am getting java heap size error as well as space out error. Therefore I wanna increase the allocated memory for Android Studio.

How to Increase allocated memory for Android Studio In Arch Linux?

Comment: Help -> Edit Custom VM Options

Answer (score 1):

I looked at my Environment Variables and had a System Variable called _JAVA_OPTIONS with the value `-Xms256m -Xmx512m,` after changing this to `-Xms256m -Xmx1024m` the max heap size increased accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `app/gradle.properties`, you can see below comments.

> Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
>
> The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
>
> Default value: -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
>
> org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

So, you can add below into your `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```